# Sharing data between objects, binding properties

Tags: oop

I have some thoughts on object data sharing.

- Lets define Class *C* with properties *p1*, *p2* (lets think that it is immutable).
- Lets have some objects *X* and *Y* of Class *C*.
- Lets create some sort of "container" *G* for the objects of Class C.
  The "container" *G* has property *gp1*.
- Lets add object X to "container" *G* and "bind" *X.p1* with *G.gp1* value. (Bind does say that when object *X* tries to get value of property *p1* it gets value of *gp1*.)
- Let's add object Y to container *G*  and "bind" *Y.p1* with *G.gp1* value.

As you may think its kind of simple thing for humans.

The only idea I think of is create interface for *p1, p2* property access. Then implement the interface in *Class C* (no shared data) and *Class GC* (with container data). And then decorate objects to add methods.

As you can see each bind adds an interface + interface implementation. Thats a lot to write and kind of ugly.

The question:
How to create this kind bind operation for every object? (without implementing DSL, using C derived langauges: java, C#, C++, php, ...)

Comment: You may be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: What is the sense to have a field in the class and to return by getter the other field in another class? It is very dangerous construction.

Comment: It could be a virtual field.

Answer (score 0):

And where is the problem? And what is the p2 for?

```
static class G{
    int gp1;
}
static class C{
    int p1,p2;
    G provider; 
    C(G provider){
        provider=this.provider;
    }
    int getP1(){
        return provider.gp1; 
    }
}
static class X extends C{
    X(G provider){
        super(provider);
    }
}
static class Y extends C{
    Y(G provider){
        super(provider);
    }
}
```

The soulution can be universal only if we'll provide the provider by its interface. But you don't want to use it. A universal solution without interfaces is impossible here.

```
interface IProvider{
    int getGp1();
}
static class G implements IProvider{
    private int gp1;
    int getGp1(){return gp1};
}
static class C{
    int p1,p2;
    IProvider provider; 
    C(IProvider provider){
        provider=this.provider;
    }
    int getP1(){
        return provider.gp1; 
    }
}
static class X extends C{
    X(G provider){
        super(provider);
    }
}
static class Y extends C{
    Y(G provider){
        super(provider);
    }
}
```

And please, notice, that having a field in the class and returning by getter the other field in another class is very non-intuitive and dangerous construction

Comment: The problem is that X and Y is constructed for particular container and can't be used without it. So to make universal object you need to create more classes and thats what I do not want.

Comment: @user1759572 It can be universal only if we'll provide the provider by its interface. But you don't want to use it. A universal solution without interfaces is impossible here.